# rounded ImageView not shown after add resource

Tags: android

this is my class for make rounded imageview

```
package customfonts;


import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView
{
    private int borderWidth = 0;
    private int viewWidth;
    private int viewHeight;
    private Bitmap image;
    private Paint paint;
    private Paint paintBorder;
    private BitmapShader shader;

    public RoundedImageView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        setup();
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        setup();
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setup();
    }

    private void setup()
    {
        // init paint
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        paintBorder = new Paint();
        setBorderColor(Color.WHITE);
        //setBorderColor(1);
        paintBorder.setAntiAlias(true);
        this.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paintBorder);
        paintBorder.setShadowLayer(2.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, Color.BLACK);
    }

    public void setBorderWidth(int borderWidth)
    {
        this.borderWidth = borderWidth;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public void setBorderColor(int borderColor)
    {
        if (paintBorder != null)
            paintBorder.setColor(borderColor);

        this.invalidate();
    }

    private void loadBitmap()
    {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) this.getDrawable();

        if (bitmapDrawable != null)
            image = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
    }

    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        // load the bitmap
        loadBitmap();

        // init shader
        if (image != null)
        {
            shader = new BitmapShader(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), false), Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
            paint.setShader(shader);
            int circleCenter = viewWidth / 2;

            // circleCenter is the x or y of the view's center
            // radius is the radius in pixels of the cirle to be drawn
            // paint contains the shader that will texture the shape
            canvas.drawCircle(circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter + borderWidth - 4.0f, paintBorder);
            canvas.drawCircle(circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter - 4.0f, paint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        int width = measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);

        viewWidth = width - (borderWidth * 2);
        viewHeight = height - (borderWidth * 2);

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    private int measureWidth(int measureSpec)
    {
        int result = 0;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
        {
            // We were told how big to be
            result = specSize;
        }
        else
        {
            // Measure the text
            result = viewWidth;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private int measureHeight(int measureSpecHeight, int measureSpecWidth)
    {
        int result = 0;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpecHeight);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpecHeight);

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
        {
            // We were told how big to be
            result = specSize;
        }
        else
        {
            // Measure the text (beware: ascent is a negative number)
            result = viewHeight;
        }

        return (result + 2);
    }
}
```

now i will use it in xml

```
            <customfonts.RoundedImageView
             android:id="@+id/profile"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:src="@drawable/photo"
             />
```

also i try use

```
 android:background="@drawable/photo"
```

and when i use or replace `customfonts.RoundedImageView` with `ImageView` its work and show my image what the problem i think its on my class code before i update it its work after update it and add some shadow its stop working any solution ?

photo for result 
 [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is that resouce available ?

```
         android:src="@drawable/photo"
```

try to add hardcode height and width for testing purpose.

```
         android:layout_width="120dp"
         android:layout_height="120dp"
```

if it works then check your activity xml architecture. it may be mismatching between layouts.